# Add standard button animation to a TextView

Tags: java, android, xml

I apologize if it might be a duplicate but couldn't find a solution.

Look at this orange button
[image]

When I click on it there's a smooth standard animation. How can I do the same on a TextView? Imagine I have an orange textView like that which behavies like a Button. How can I add the same animation to it? Thank you so much

Comment: Have you already tried with a ripple drawable as a background?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but honestly I don't know how to do it XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting API 23 or greater you can use a combination of `background` and `foreground` properties:

```xml
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true" />
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! But unfortunately I have a Spinner with several textViews, but if I put this code inside the TextView the items don't get selected :( Do you know why?

Comment: *Resolved by deleting clickable and focusable.

Comment: Just a question and I won't disturb you anymore... is there a way to change the colour of the foreground?

Comment: @AlessandroF what do you mean? You mean the color of the ripple effect?

Answer (score 1):

Create the ripple effect as a selector xml file:

ripple.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

then set that as a background to your view:

```
android:background="@drawable/ripple"
```

You can edit the colours and shapes in the xml to match the style you want